# Changing display of tables based on forms in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby, html-table

I have some JSON that I pull in and read into an object `@items`. A second object, say 'items_old', holds the items from yesterday. :

```
[
 {
  {
    "id": "A",
    "description": "a_description_one"
    "value": some_alphanumeric_string
  }, 
  {
    "id": "B",
    "description": "b_description_one"
    "value": some_alphanumeric_string
  }, 
  {
    "id": "C",
    "description": "c_description_one"
    "value": some_alphanumeric_string
  }
 }, 
 {
  {
    "id": "A",
    "description": "a_description_3"
    "value": some_alphanumeric_string
  }, 
  {
    "id": "B",
    "description": "b_description_3"
    "value": some_alphanumeric_string
  }, 
  {
    "id": "C",
    "description": "c_description_3"
    "value": some_alphanumeric_string
  }
 }, 
 ...
]
```

My goal is to output a tables, as follows, in HTML:

```
 ----------------------------------------------------
|  C value  | C description  |  Count       | Change |
|----------------------------------------------------|
|some string|it's description|times appeared| change |
 ----------------------------------------------------
```

This table works as follows: somewhere in the index file, there's a drop down box with all the ids from the code above (ie. A, B, C). When an option is selected, a table is loaded that looks like the one above. It takes each value of the chosen id and puts it in a table. When a value occurs twice, it's concatenated into one item, and the count is increased. Counts are compared to the ones from the day before, and the difference is displayed.

Comment: Something about the data structure doesn't make sense. Are you sure you mean to have an keyless hash embedded in an array at the top-level?

Comment: What is the specific question you are asking? Is there code you have written?